# Not able to Install openCV 2.4.9 on raspberry pi 2 model B

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, opencv

I am trying to install openCV 2.4.9 on raspberry pi 2 but facing some error regarding libtiff4-dev image format.

[image]

I have tried with 'libtiff5-dev' also but it is not working.

[image]

I dont know what the issue is, I installed same openCV in my other micro SD card 3-4 month before that time it worked fine.

I have already install python 2.7.9.

I have tried searching for this error but was not able to find a solution, can anyone help me? Tell me what wrong I am doing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using jessie, what's wrong with just `apt-get install opencv`?  2.4.9 is the current version.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean). You need to do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

before attempting to install it. If this still does not work you may need to add the repository that `libtiff4-dev` comes from, but it could be that `libtiff4-dev` is no longer included in any repositories, in that case, you may be out of luck.

**UPDATE:**

I just did `sudo apt-get update` on my Pi and then `sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev` and I was able to install it, so it is still in the repo.

Comment: Yes I have tried with 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade' but still it didn't worked.

Comment: I am doing this as I have to install openCV, I am following http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/ this link

Comment: I am using raspbian Jessie version.

Comment: Those instructions look to be an incredible waste of time since [openCV is in the Raspbian repos](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/opencv/), as is a `python-opencv` (2.4.9) package.

Answer (score 1):

To fix unmet dependencies, use sudo apt-get -f install

If it doesn't worked out then try with aptitude

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

`sudo aptitude install <Your_package>`